# Set expire time for set ioredis

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm trying to set an expire time for a set of values in ioredis nodejs. I can add a set to reids using this command

```
redis.sadd('set', 1, 3, 5, 7);
```

But I need to set an expire time for this set. How can I do this?

Comment: `EXPIRE`, `EXPIREAT`, `PEXPIRE` and `PEXPIREAT`. You have many choices.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [expire](https://redis.io/commands/expire)

> redis.expire('set', 10);

General syntax for expire is `EXPIRE KEY_NAME TIME_IN_SECONDS`.

There are [multiple](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-3-commands-in-redis/3-7-other-commands/3-7-3-expiring-keys/) ways to do it, only if you want to try others.